# Is it correct and natural to say "think the same about something" in the sense of having the same opinion on somethin as on something?

Tags: phrase-choice

Let's say someone asks this question.

> What do you think of this phone?

And I want to say that I have the same opinion on **that** phone as I have on the other phones. Can I say the following?

> I think the same about that phone as I think about the other phones.

If it doesn't sound natural, what would native English speakers say?

Comment: "The phone" has some implication of phones in general, as in "The phone has been a curse since its invention." Substitute *this* for "the" in the question? Depending on how close your are to the particular phone in question, you may have to substitute *that* for "the" in the answer.

Comment: The simplest thing to say is: "I have the same opinion about that phone as I have about all the other phones you showed me."  Some other variants would be as follows.   "All the phones seem the same to me." "I can't see much difference between the different phones."